# Does Stack Overflow support code bidding?

Tags: support

Does Stack Overflow help us to sell and purchase code snippets or complete projects?

Comment: Nope, that's not something Stack Overflow does.

Comment: There are several services that can fit in the general direction of what you're looking for. For example CodeCanyon, BinPress and CodersClan. (Disclaimer: I'm a founder at CodersClan)

Comment: Although SOOOO many times when someone has posted a "please write my code for me" question I've wanted to respond with my hourly rates.

Comment: @TabAlleman - though I've not see rates explicitly posted, I have seen them referenced

Comment: If we can't trade code for money, can StackOverflow let us exchange reputation points for gift cards and pizza?

Comment: @Blazemonger Why aren't we funding this? :P

Comment: Why is this so downvoted? It's a valid question.

Comment: @hitch.united - It's tagged feature request. People don't want this feature.

Comment: It seems like there's a business opportunity for CodersClan or one of its competitors to support a "make quick SO link", so someone can comment "This isn't an appropriate answer for StackOverflow because ____, but if it gets closed and you don't want to do any work for yourself and you want to hire someone to write your code for you, I'm available at `<CodersClan link>`." :)

Comment: No, otherwise stack would actually overflow!

Comment: @Orchestrator you should take note of abarnert's comment.

Comment: Thanks! @abarnert. Is your intention that we would somehow get integrated with Stack Overflow's UI when closing a task? Or just that coders would have the ability to provide a link to a "hire me" link?

Comment: @Orchestrator: I was just thinking of you providing a "hire me" link that could be pasted into a comment (similar to the way [DebuggEx](https://www.debuggex.com/) has an "embed on Stack Overflow" button that just generates something to paste into an answer, rather than trying to integrate into the answer UI, for regex questions). Anyway, I was only half-serious; I suspect most people asking questions for which the only right answer is "hire someone" aren't actually likely to hire someone anyway… but I could be wrong (and you'd probably know better than me).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not currently support this feature, and it seems like it would be wildly out of the scope of what it’s currently designed to do ([“collectively increas[e] the sum total of *good* programming knowledge in the world”](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/)), so I doubt it’d ever be implemented. I’m sure there are other services out there that support this use case just fine, and Stack Overflow needn’t compete in this area.

Comment: Hello [reversal badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal)!