# Why is this heavily downvoted question not yet removed from Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, downvotes, meta

I have a heavily down-voted question ([Does Stack Overflow support code bidding?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252460/does-stack-overflow-support-code-bidding)). I raised a moderation attention flag, and it was **marked as helpful**.
However, my question is not yet removed from **Meta Stack Overflow**.

What is the **procedure / criteria**  to remove my question from Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: a) That question has an upvoted answer, it won't get deleted by the system. b) That is a question on meta, where downvotes are different. Keeping the question around lets it serve as a source of information about what the site will and won't do.

Comment: I wouldn't be so hard on yourself as to say it's a stupid question, downvotes happen. Especially on Meta. In some small way it's useful to have the question around as it may help other people wondering the same thing - and don't forget that some of the most heavily downvoted content on Meta comes from SO staff.

Comment: Through, it sounds more like a support question rather than a FR.

Comment: The question is useful. The downvotes mean people don't want that, on balance.

Comment: related: [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they \*really\* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

Comment: Here, seeing that votes on meta don't really matter, have an upvote to make you feel better :)

Comment: May I ask why you even want it deleted? Meta doesn't have any Meaningless Internet Points (commonly termed "rep") to lose.

Comment: I have actually been ask that same question in real life from someone who wanted to **start** using StackOverflow just for that.

Comment: More than whether such a feature exists or not, what's more important is the reason you think your participation needs to be removed.

Comment: Sometimes [failure is more instructive to leave up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/info-contacted-by-spammers-ispirer-systems-referencing-stack-overflow/274959#274959) so others learn

Comment: This question is listed in the Hot Meta Posts. Are we meta-effecting a meta post???

Comment: In the true spirit of meta, downvoting this question.

Comment: Don't remove your question, it's a perfectly good question (even if the answer is a resounding 'No')

Comment: oh, I just downvoted it

Comment: While down voted meta questions don't affect your rep, they count against the "positive question record" needed to gain several badges. Not to mention that you might not want your account associated with some questions, down voted or not.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Your question has the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag. Downvotes mean "I disagree with this feature suggestion".

Many people don't want that feature request, hence the downvotes.

Also note that your question *has* an upvoted answer, so the system won't delete it.

Comment: Does this mean a unanimously downvoted feature-request would be deleted? This seems strange, surely that's valuable information (that no-one likes a suggestion). If deleted, lower rep (sub-10k) users may repost it!

Comment: @AndyHayden unanimously downvoted feature-request will probably not be implemented. You're right, we should keep it so others can see it was already suggested.

Answer (score 55):

Downvotes on SO mean something like "This is a bad question, and shouldn't be here."

Downvotes on meta usually mean "No, we shouldn't do this", "This wouldn't work well", "I disagree with your opinion". Sometimes they mean "This is a bad question." But often a lot of downvotes means you had a question that elicited a response, which is probably a good thing.

There's no penalty to your rep for meta downvotes. Don't delete it; it's a question someone else might have, and it's not a bad question. The comments and upvoted answer are potentially helpful to the community.

In future, consider using the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag for things you want an answer to and that aren't really a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: Be aware that just retagging it discussion does not make it one. It should not read like a feature-request if it shouldn't be one.

Comment: Well, it SHOULD mean this, but in reality, in most cases, it means "hang him higher". That's why I pledge for transparency and the source of ALL votes should be visible.

Comment: Of course, feature requests can evolve from discussions. But if a user marks a question as a discussion, imo this should be understood as such. Unfortunately, that just doesn't work here. Maybe it also plays a role that the audience is afraid of a feature-request that potentially could evolve from a discussion and want to destroy it in the first place.

Answer (score 38):

When it comes to deleting stuff, we hate doing the following:

- Wasting time other people put into answering your question
- Throwing away any achievements other people earned by answering your question

That's why [the section on licensing in our terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing)
(*Subscriber Content*) is as specific as it is.

Meta sites are a bit more relaxed from the parent sites they're attached to, but deleting a question makes every contribution attached to it effectively *gone* as well, we try to not do that unless the whole *lot* of it would be better off headed toward that great fun house in the sky.

But, that doesn't mean it's a weight around your elbows forever, you'll just need to contact us in order to break it away from your profile. Mods *do* pass these requests along to us, but to be sure, contact us directly.

Answer (score 8):

I have just one point to make here, and yes I am posting this as an answer because I believe this is **important** and can't just be a comment.

**Downvoting** does not necessarily mean something is **harmful**, at least here at **meta**, especially when you are requesting for a **new feature**. Because, it might also mean that *folks don't agree with you or your request or(whatever it concerns you in your question)*.

> What is the procedure / criteria to remove a question from Meta Stack Overflow?

More than whether such a feature exists or not, what's more important is the **reason** you think your **participation** needs to be **removed**. Man, you have given your **time** to participate here, and expected something out of it. Ok, fine, things didn't go as per your expectations, but then you were **addressed** and you got an **answer**.

*And, to prove that people have addressed your question and understood it, there were upvotes on the answer.*