# Most low-quality posts are comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts

Today I reviewed **Low Quality Posts**. From which near about half of them are comments as an answer.

Most of them mention in the answer that they do not have enough reputation, so they post it as a answer (obviously it is low-quality post and recommended for deletion).

Should Stack Overflow provide the low reputation points people to comment so we can decrease low quality posts on Stack Overflow?

Or any other way we can allow low reputation points users to comment on a post (like limit number of comments on a post)?

Comment: There is no way to track a new comment being posted, so allowing low rep users to post them will open the gate for spam comments.

Comment: You can decrease the number of low quality posts on SO by deleting them; this is what the review queue is for.

Comment: @downvoter is any one comment reason for downvote?

Comment: @2mkgz yes you right.

Comment: @ketan, the down-votes are probably because [user's are losing their keys like Tim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/285413)

Comment: Downvotes on Meta mean disagreement (in this case, with your suggested feature).

Comment: @ketan [see this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291770/why-is-this-heavily-downvoted-question-not-yet-removed-from-meta-stack-overflow/291772#291772) to understand the downvotes reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That queue exists in order to help Stack Overflow to get rid of low quality posts.

Allowing everyone to comment could lead to many spam, "I'm having the same problem" and many other polluting comments.

When a user have >50 reputation it means that they gave good answers or asked a good question, or edited posts. It's an indication that the user might be ready to write good and valuable comments.

I'm not saying that everyone that has <50 reputation won't write good comments, it's just the history that taught Stack Overflow that newcomers usually don't know what's the purpose of comments.

Answer (score 2):

There are options that could provide *some* of the benefit of allowing new users to request clarification by commenting, while avoiding *some* of the negatives (spam, me-too, etc.).

For example: Allow them to post comments, only on questions, only visible to the OP, auto-deleted after any of (X minutes passes, OP posts a comment, OP edits the question, OP accepts an answer) happens, and with a clear notice saying all that and explaining that this is just a temporary comment to ask for clarification.

I don't particularly love that example. And I can't think of any other that I do love. But anyone who thinks this is a problem that needs to be solved has to come up with something *like* that, but better, because allowing normal comments for new users, or allowing comments as answers to stand, are definitely not going to work.

Answer (score -2):

I was going through the low quality post queue (like you did and noticed the exact same thing) Many of them clearly are not an answers, but...

I understand that a answer that's meant to be a comment isn't allowed... but it got me thinking... how can a low rep user request clarification from someone who asked a question?

Here is an example answer-comment:

> Is there any error when executing the sql statement? are columns
>   allowed null value as you only pass @d1 and @d2? P.S.: I would just
>   put this as comment, but not enough reputation.

**It seems to me their only options are:**

1. Can't request clarification at all
2. Comment as a question... then have it deleted (and feel the wrath of the community, as seen below)

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post
>   - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. – [High Rep User]
>
> @[High Rep User], I don't know why you comment based on a known fact that I
>   agreed and already stated that 'I don't have enough reputation.' in my
>   original post. You can suggest me an alternative way instead of repeat
>   what I said. – [Low Rep User]
>
> @[Low Rep User], your post appeared in the Low Quality Post Review Queue because
>   someone flagged your answer. It does not matter that you do not have
>   enough rep to comment. Your post is clearly a comment and not an
>   answer. SO is very strict to delete comments posted as answer. I would
>   recommend you to delete this or actually make this into an answer,
>   otherwise, this is not worthy of remaining as an answer. – [High Rep User]

While I agree with what [High Rep User] said, that this definitely isn't a valid answer, what options does a new user have?

It seems sort of counter intuitive to me atleast. I get that they need to to build up rep first. But think about a scenario of wanting to answer a specific question:

1. You know the tech stack
2. You think you know the answer (You're brand new to SO. Time to give back! #excitement)
3. But there is some info lacking... but your hands are tied from ANY means of allowed interaction with the OP.
4. Sadness

**We might be losing some potentially good/viable answers in this process?**

Comment: *"We might be losing some potentially good/viable answers in this process?"* - we might, but it's a trade-off, we're also preventing low-quality comments. And new users should learn quickly that *"I'm not supposed to do this but..."* doesn't fly around here!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I guess if someone is serious about joining SO, they'll bite the (tiny) bullet and build up the min rep like we all have... my fear is that this process of learning by bumping your head against the metaphorical wall might also scare people off? Ultimately I know we will  be left with the serious participants who went through this min rep process like everyone else, I'm basically just wondering if this "rite of passage" can't potentially be improved without impacting the quality of the site?

Comment: So what is your counter-proposal? Lower the rep requirement? Allow users to use answers as comments if they can't comment? Both of those seem like bad ideas to me. (O/t, that's: *"rite of passage"*)

Comment: @RohanBüchner, if the [Low Rep User] wanted, he could have added an answer in case of that condition, rather than just making it look like a comment. If he had added some answer there, then it would have been worth keeping. But that's not what the [Low Rep User] did. It could have been considered an answer if it was like "If there is problem with X, and some more questions, then you can try Y" or something close, so that there is something that can be considered an answer there

Comment: @jonrsharpe; Thanks for making me seem literate :P To be honest I 100% agree with you, 50 is such a low requirement as it stands, it was just a thought I wanted to discuss/get clarity on

Comment: @ArunA.S; true he could have formatted it much better. In hindsight, he could have phrased it in correct answer form, maybe given a few answer scenarios etc. Maybe this is just something you pick up after going through the motions of interacting with SO & the community after some time.

Comment: @RohanBüchner , yes. one can only learn about the rules of SO if he/she take part in the community. Every new user will make mistakes. That is why we, the more experienced users exist to guide them in the right path. Even though it may seem harsh, we must take proper action so that they learn about how the community works so that they can contribute to the community in their own way in the future.

Comment: As a side note, your example of "the wrath of the community" doesn't seem the slightest bit wrathful (or insulting, or cliquish, or anything else negative) to me. And anyone who takes it as wrathful probably isn't going to fit in at SO anyway. (Imagine what'll happen the first time he comments on a bad question and sees some _real_ wrath…)

Comment: @abarnert, key there being "to me", you're not every other person in the world, as such different strokes for different folks. You'll be surprised as to how drastically different people react to each other (to the same situation)... something that's meant to be constructive can often be misconstrued as someone being aggressive. Especially if you're new...

Comment: @RohanBüchner: That's exactly what the second half of my comment is about. There certainly _are_ people who will, e.g., find even the nicest possible statement of any rule of any community to be wrathful… but those people are just not going to fit it on SO.